# Which Control sent an InputEvent in Godot 4

Tags: godot4

Using Godot 4.1, I am trying to achieve the following. I dynamically create some `TextureRect` nodes, and then assign handlers to mouse clicks, like this (just for the example):

```
var tr = TextureRect.new()
# ...
tr.gui_input.connect(_on_texture_rect_gui_input)
```

According to the docs, the handler receives one parameter, the event itself. So I have this handler:

```
func _on_texture_rect_gui_input(event: InputEvent):
    if event is InputEventMouseButton:
        if event.button_index == MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT and event.pressed:
            print("Image clicked, but which one?")
```

But as said above, I create many of these `TextureRect` objects dynamically. How do I know which one received the click?

`InputEvent` does not seem have this info (like `sender` is common in some other languages), and I have no other ideas tbh. :) This makes me think I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. How am I supposed to do this properly?

One idea I had was that I could connect the event on the container, and not on individual images. That way when the container event fires, I guess I could find out which image received the click, based on the click and image coordinates. But this is really messy, there must be a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When connecting the singal you could use `Callable.bind()` on the receiving method to add the texture rect as a parameter, i.e. `tr.gui_input.connect(_on_texture_rect_gui_input.bind(tr))`. Parameters bound with this method will be added to the end of the parameter list so the `_on_texture_rect_gui_input` should look something like this:

```
func _on_texture_rect_gui_input(event: InputEvent, image: TextureRect):
    if event is InputEventMouseButton:
        if event.button_index == MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT and event.pressed:
            # use image for processing of the input
```

Note that when you default `image` to a value you can also connect without the additional bind. In that case `image` will be that default value.

Comment: Ah ok, so the trick is in Callable. This is a little underdocumented, I never thought to look there. Also it's not an idea I've seen in other languages or frameworks this way. Anyway, this is great, thanks a lot!